# Pull expression in query with limit/default?

Tags: datomic

How can I use limit/default in at pull expression in a query? Given a cardinality-many attribute, how can I control how many of its values is returned (default is max 1000 values!).

(Found it hard to figure out the correct syntax from the documentation/examples)

Answer (score 2):

**Limit (for cardinality-many attributes)**

Return max 2 values of cardinality-many attribute `:ns/ints`:

```
[:find  (pull ?a [(limit :ns/ints 2)])
 :where [?a :ns/str ?b]]
```

Return all values of cardinality-many attribute `:ns/ints`:

```
[:find  (pull ?a [(limit :ns/ints nil)])
 :where [?a :ns/str ?b]]
```

**Default**

Return default value `2000` if attribute `:ns/ints` has no value:

```
[:find  (pull ?a [(default :ns/ints 2000)])
 :where [?a :ns/str ?b]]
```

Return default values `2000` and `2001` if cardinality-many attribute `:ns/ints` has no values:

```
[:find  (pull ?a [(default :ns/ints [2000 2001])])
 :where [?a :ns/str ?b]]
```